# WildFly 21 - No routing provider found for default-server; using legacy provider based on static configuration

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-21

I got this warning while I run wildFly server

```
16:54:56,327 WARN  [org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) WFLYCLWEBUT0007: No routing provider found for default-server; using legacy provider based on static configuration
```

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of this warining, you have to **add the following entries** to your **Wildfly** `standalone.xml`:

Add the `org.wildfly.extension.clustering.web` extension inside the `<extensions>` tag

```
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.clustering.web"/>
```

Add the `<distributable-web>` subsystem inside the `<profile>` tag

**Wildfly 21**:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:distributable-web:2.0" default-session-management="default" default-single-sign-on-management="default">
        <infinispan-session-management name="default" cache-container="web" granularity="SESSION">
            <primary-owner-affinity/>
        </infinispan-session-management>
        <infinispan-single-sign-on-management name="default" cache-container="web" cache="sso"/>
        <infinispan-routing cache-container="web" cache="routing"/>
    </subsystem>
```

**Wildfly 23 and 26**:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:distributable-web:2.0" default-session-management="default" default-single-sign-on-management="default">
        <infinispan-session-management name="default" cache-container="web" granularity="SESSION">
            <local-affinity/>
        </infinispan-session-management>
        <infinispan-single-sign-on-management name="default" cache-container="web" cache="sso"/>
        <local-routing/>
    </subsystem>
```